# ASP.Net MVC claims authorization and authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, authorization, claims-based-identity

Please help me decide how to do the authorization for my project.

The project is written in ASP.Net MVC and is an intranet application that lets users log in via Active Directory.

Users can either be Junior Lecturer, Senior Lecturer, HOD or SuperUser. That's easy enough with roles but the situation is more complicated than that because those roles are based on whatever information you are looking at. For instance, a Junior Lecturer can only see information for students that he lectures etc.

As far as I understand it, that's where claims come in. I should assign modules or students to a user.

But the process if further complicated because there is no list of AD usernames and their students/modules in any single place.

I need to be able to check several databases to see if a user should be allowed to see the information.

Sometimes though, a user who has access to see certain information will not pass any of those checks. Because of that I will have to create a database with an AD username, their role and their subjects/students.

So my question is really regarding authorization. Is it possible for me to have that level of control on the claims and how would I assign them and check them?

If its not possible - how am i going to do this authorization?

Having an if statement at the start of every Action in every Controller feels wrong - but that's all my colleagues can come up with.

Comment: I did manage to solve a problem a bit closer to what you are having recently. I'm still writing the blog posts, but [this](http://blog.dinklabs.com/2015/11/mvc-fine-grained-identity-access-control-1.html) is my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a class that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute then you have the freedom to do whatever complicated authorization process you see fit. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536785/net-web-api-override-authorizationfilter/31537480#31537480) on how to do so.

Here is some code I am using to query and cache AD roles:

```
private static Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, bool> groupIdentityCache = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, bool>();
```

..

```
public static bool UserHasRole(IIdentity identity, string groupShortName)     
{
    // (we rename our actual AD roles to shorter ones relevant to the site
    // e.g. [MyAuthorizeAttribute(Roles = "Support,Admin")])
    if (!AdLongGroupNames.ContainsKey(groupShortName.ToUpper())) return false;
    string fullADGroupName = AdLongGroupNames[groupShortName.ToUpper()];            
    Tuple<string, string> key = new Tuple<string, string>(identity.Name.ToUpper(), groupShortName.ToUpper());
    if (!groupIdentityCache.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME"))      
        {
            using (GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, fullADGroupName))
            {
                using (UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, GetLogin(identity)))
                {
                    groupIdentityCache[key] = userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(groupPrincipal);
                }
            }
        }                
    }            
    return groupIdentityCache[key];
}

public static string GetLogin(IIdentity identity)
{
    string[] parts = identity.Name.Split('\\');
    if (parts.Count() < 2) return parts[0]; else return parts[1];
}
```

If you cache role memberships, you must also clear the cache on Session_Start for changes to take effect.

You can modify this solution to include roles from non-AD sources (such as a databases of class membership etc.) by adding to the groupIdentityCache dictionary. Modifying groupIdentityCache can also help when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Having an 'if' statement is wrong, it will cost you long iteration and a huge misuse of memory.

Basically, you can control your authorization at every level almost using the `authorize` attribute.

However, you do need a well-built entity to do so, in order to not get lost withing all of the rules. It is very recommended that you will have a proper plan of your authorization scheme before committing this.

You can try to use `switch` statements instead, which will be a lot better in practice.

Please note:

[Authorization Article](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/) that might help you understand.

Comment: Where should I use the switch statement? Thanks for the article - the problem is though that activities are not the part I'm having trouble with. In fact, the only activity I really need to have is READ. The problem is, does this user have access to this module? Where should I put the checking code?